# Segmentation fault due to default arguments using eigen library

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, eigen, default-value

I have been running into a strange memory issue in one of my C++ classes, relating to the value of a default variable that is pass-by-const-ref.
When I create a `Camera` object (definition below) **without providing a second argument** (in which case the default `DEFAULT_LOC` is used), it segfaults 90% of the time.

The problem class is a camera class that internally uses the Eigen/Geometry module to control its location in space.  The header file for the class is as follows:

```
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

// The type used to represent transforms
typedef Eigen::Isometry3f Transform;
typedef Eigen::Vector3f Point;

// Camera class, contains methods that facilitate active vision
class Camera {
public:
  // The dimension used for width and height, in pixels
  using Dim = uint16_t;

  // struct representing camera internal description, required to properly project to/from image-space
  struct CameraDescription {
    Dim width;
    Dim height;
    double focalLength;
  };

  // A Camera object requires a description of its internals, and a transform representing position and orientation
  // The z-axis in the camera transform is the direction the camera is facing
  // The y-axis in the camera transform is the upwards direction in the camera space
  // The x-axis in the camera transform is the left direction in the camera space

  const static Transform DEFAULT_LOC;
  Camera(const CameraDescription &desc, const Transform &loc=DEFAULT_LOC);

  // Get the camera description
  CameraDescription getDescription() const {return _desc;}

  Transform getTransform() const {return _loc;}
  void setTransform(const Transform &tf) {_loc = tf; _origin=_loc.translation();}

  void pointAt(Point dir, double angle=0.0);
private:
  // Transform used to denote an intrinsics matrix
  typedef Eigen::Matrix3f Intrinsics;

  // Camera internal details
  CameraDescription _desc;

  // Constructed transform, used to project from camera pixel space to world space
  Intrinsics _transform;
  // Stored upon setting _transform since this is expected to be used often in cast()
  Point _origin;

  // Camera location in space
  Transform _loc;

  // Static helper method that converts a CameraDescription to an intrinsics matrix for projection
  static Intrinsics _convert(const CameraDescription &desc);
};
```

The DEFAULT_LOC static variable is defined in the header file (camera.cpp) as:

```
  const Transform Camera::DEFAULT_LOC((Eigen::Matrix4f() <<
             0, 0, 1, 0,
             1, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 1, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 1).finished());
```

The constructor does no additional work beyond simply initializing all private member variables using the supplied arguments:

```
 Camera::Camera(const CameraDescription &desc, const Transform &loc)
   : _desc(desc), _loc(loc), _transform(_convert(_desc)), _origin(_loc.translation()) {}
```

Removing the default value and setting it to something like `Camera(const CameraDescription &desc, const Transform &loc=Transform::Identity());`, instead of the const static global variable solves the segfault issue.

As far as I am aware, default values are statically bound, so at compile-time it should set `loc` to the address of `DEFAULT_LOC`, correct?  Is the static default value at a random memory location before the code is run and it is initialized?  Could that or something like it cause a change of address?  If that is the case then I can see why loc would cause a segfault, but I'm not sure if that is what is going on here.

EDIT: The code that causes the segfault is:

```
Camera c = Camera(CameraDescription{100, 100, 515});
```

No other variable involved is declared static

Comment: *(Please provide code that causes the crash so that requests for clarification like the following are not necessary.)* Is the `Camera` object that causes this a static variable? The [tag:static-order-fiasco] is common enough to have its own tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JaMiT No other static variables involved, I updated the question to reflect that

Comment: What you provide is still no [mre]. Post all necessary files (ideally reduced to a minimum) and the steps you took to compile and link these to reproduce the observed behavior.

Comment: Without context, the code that causes the segfault defines a variable with [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration), despite not using the `static` keyword. (If we cannot see that it is inside a function, then we may assume it is at namespace scope.) If this is the case, you have caught me being imprecise, as I should have asked about "a variable with static storage duration" instead of "a static variable". If this is not the case, please add a (do-nothing) function so that the definition of `c` is inside a function definition.